# notification dynamic large icon not working android

Tags: android, bitmap, notifications

i want to show dynamic icon (generated by passing text) in notification area !

set small icon mathod uses already exists drawable package icon so i can't use that .

set large icon mathod uses bitmap image so i m generating bitmap image and passing it to setlargeicon mathod here is my code

```
   Bitmap b1 = drawText(String.valueOf(level),24,24);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setLargeIcon(b1)
            .setTicker("better level "+level);      

            Intent intent1 = new Intent( context1, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context1, 786 , intent1, 0);
            builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification notif = builder.build();
            notif.flags=Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;


            mNotificationManager.notify(786, notif);
```

i am not getting any notification .. if i use set small icon mathod with ic_launcher image it shows notification.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to set a small icon.

```
Bitmap b1 = drawText(String.valueOf(level),24,24);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.someIcon)
        .setLargeIcon(b1)
        .setTicker("better level "+level);    `
```